# 'SchemaMetadata' is not a member type of type 'Self.Schema'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, graphql, apollo-ios

I'm working in xcode project (xcode --version 14 && swift --version 5.7) and build an apollo client project in which after generating query.graphql file I'm getting this error in Schema Package which is generated after executing following commands:-

```
to build apollo-io-cli
git clone https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-ios.git
cd apollo-ios
make build-cli
find . -name apollo-ios-cli
copy the found apollo-io-cli to your directory where  you have schema.json file 
run from that directory
./apollo-ios-cli generate
this will generate the swift files for graphql
```

here i'm using apollo-ios version 1.0.2

[here is the screen shot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1X8xy.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, You named schema as "schema" which brings conflicts. Try to rename it to something else